# Frequency response of a bandpass filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response

I want to see the frequency response of 1024 order bandpass filter in MATLAB.

The sampling frequency is 16kHz and the pass band frequency is [376Hz 480Hz]. I have implemented the bandpass filter using inbuilt function `fir1` as `b1 = fir1(1024,[376/8000 480/8000],'bandpass')`.
To plot the frequency response of the filter, I have used the inbuilt function `freqz(b1,1,10000,16000)`.

My doubt is -3dB frequency obtained from the MATLAB plot should be at the pass band cut off frequency i.e at 376Hz and 480Hz right?[image]

Now I tried to plot the magnitude response using fdatool in MATLAB, by providing the following details:
FIR equiripple filter was selected
order=1024
Fs=16000
Fstop1=256
Fpass1=376
Fpass2=480
Fstop2=600
Wstop1=1
Wpass=1
Wstop2=1 and the plot obtained was as below:

[image]

There is difference in the frequency response

Comment: You edited your question as I was answering. Originally, you were using a order N = 128 FIR filter and wondering why the cut-off was not at -6dB. Seems you've figured out you needed to increase the order to get the desired result. Hopefully my answer still explains why ;)

Comment: Why is the frequency response obtained using Matlab fdatool showing normalized gain of 0dB at passband cut off frequencies

Comment: You're using an equiripple design. That's a different method. Change to `window` method  and you'll get your -6dB back if you feel like it ;)

Answer (score 1):

`fir1` designs FIR filters using the *window method*. Per the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fir1.html#bulla52-Wn):

> The cutoff frequency is the frequency at which the normalized gain of the filter is –6 dB.

However, for the cut-off you specify to be at -6dB, you need to have appropriate transition bandwidth. I'm assuming you know what the *window method* for designing FIR filters is. If you don't, I suggest you [study some examples](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/design-examples-of-fir-filters-using-window-method/).

Long story short, the transition bandwidth is related to the design window's main-lobe width, which is itself related to the design window's length.
For example, `fir1` uses a *hamming* window by default, which has main lobe width of $8\pi/M$, $M$ being the length of the window.

**The smaller $M$ is, the larger your transition bandwidth is**.
As a matter of fact, you can estimate that the first side lobes on either part of the main lobe will have peaks at approximately $\omega_l - 1/2 \cdot8\pi/ M$ and $\omega_h + 1/2 \cdot8\pi/ M$, $\omega_l$ and $\omega_h$ being the cut-off frequencies for your band-pass. (*Note: $\pi$ is the normalized nyquist frequency, so replace with $f_s/2 = 8000$ in your case*)

Here are a few examples using your specs. Notice with $M$ increasing, the transition band sharpens, and you get closer to that $-6$dB at $376\, Hz$ and $480 \, Hz$ you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: @Deepa did jdip answer your question to your satisfaction?

Comment: @DanBoschen won't notify if the user hasn't commented on the post itself