# Derivation of a non-ideal low-pass rectangular windowed FIR filter

Tags: finite-impulse-response, lowpass-filter, derivation

I have been trying to understand certain aspects of FIR filter design which have frankly annoyed me for some time such as exactly why the critical frequency $\omega_c$ in a low-pass FIR filter is mapped to the $-6\;\text{dB}$ point for a non-ideal low-pass FIR filter and also why the critical frequency is mapped to point halfway between the transition band $\omega_t$. Below I will show my logic up until now.

If we take the ideal low-pass filter in the frequency domain, $H_{ideal}(\omega)$, with the critical/crossing frequency $\omega_c$, and take the inverse discrete-time Fourier transform, we get some response $h_{ideal}(n)$.
If we window this function with a rectangular window for simplicity but it could be any other window $w(n)$, we get the following time-domain result: $$h(n) = h_{ideal}(n) \times w(n)$$
As we know, multiplication in the time-domain is convolution in the frequency domain and vice-versa, thus
$$H(\omega) = H_{ideal}(\omega) * W(\omega)$$
This analytic solution gives all of the properties of the filter, such as for a window of length N, giving N coefficients, how can we derive the attenuation, the location of the shifted critical frequency and the length of the transition band.

I have tried to solve this convolution before and gave up as I essentially found myself in an infinite integration by parts loop. If the analytical solution is perhaps too complicated, could anyone point me in the direction of how the properties of a filter with a particular window are actually derived ?

Comment: "*The result of this convolution [...] transition band.*". This is confusing. I think you should rephrase: "This analytic solution gives all of the properties of the filter, such as for a window of length $N$, giving $N$ coefficients, how can we derive the attenuation, the location of the shifted critical frequency and the length of the transition band"

Comment: @Jdip Thanks for the recommendation and the changes should be reflected in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties of a filter designed using the window method are dependent on two parameters:

- The length of the window
- The design window function

---

**Long story short:**

- The transition bandwidth is approximately equal to the window's main lobe width, which is itself dependent on the window function AND window length.  For example, a rectangular window of length $M$ has main side lobe width $\dfrac{4\pi}{M}$ (including the negative half, see @RickarySanchez's comment), whereas a hamming window of length $M$ has main side lobe width $\dfrac{8\pi}{M}$. For the same length, the rectangular window hence has a sharper transition width.
- The attenuation depends on the window's side lobe height, which is itself dependent on the window function. For example, a rectangular window of length $M$ has first side-lobe height at $-13\,\text{dB}$ while a hamming window of length $M$ has first side-lobe height at $-41\,\text{dB}$. For the same length, the hamming window will therefore have better attenuation in the stop-band.
  *Less important but worth noting: **for a given window**, the attenuation also depends on the transition bandwidth (the sharper the transition, the better the attenuation).*
- For the cut-off $\omega_c$ to be at $-6 \,\text{dB}$, the transition bandwidth needs to be sharp enough. An illustration can be found in a [previous answer of mine](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/84857/63763).

---

**Further reading**

1. Read [this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/sasp/Window_Method_FIR_Filter.html) to understand the window method for FIR low-pass filters and how the parameters affect the resulting filter. [This](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/filter-specs-window-parameters-in-finite-impulse-response-filter-design/) is also a great reference.
2. Read [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/design-examples-of-fir-filters-using-window-method/) to see example designs based on [2](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/filter-specs-window-parameters-in-finite-impulse-response-filter-design/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the width of the main lobe of a rectangular window is $\frac{2 \pi}{M}$ radians/sample or $\frac{4 \pi}{M}$ including the negative half